# Implementing MFA in Okta

Tags: okta

How do I programatically implement MFA in Okta ? My requirements are something like this:

1. For some users, I want to use Okta Verify and some additional security questions.
2. For some other users, I want to use Google Authentication along with some additional security questions.
3. For some other users, I just want to use SMS authentication.

What are the API's/SDK's that I have to use to implement these use cases ?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this using the [Authn APIs](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/authn.html), or alternatively, use the [Sign-In Widget](http://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget.html), which implements these API's for you.

Note, if you are implementing it yourself: the authn flow is driven by policies, so you wouldn't do something like "for this user, prompt for Okta Verify". Rather, you would configure the MFA scenarios via the Okta admin pages (probably by assigning these users to groups with different Sign-On Policies). When authenticating, you will receive a response from the server for enrolling/challenging via the various factors.

Answer (score 0):

for point 3, you can use the OKTA MFA API.
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/